# How to create draggable panel without title in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, draggable, panel

I want to drag my panel without title when I drag any part of it. I already know how to remove title from panel and I know how to drag it with title bar. But i don't know how to drag without title.. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [my example](http://it-skills.su/sosamples/webspark46/dragpanel/index.html)

//Application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="init(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.dragpanel.MyPanel;

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            var panel:MyPanel = new MyPanel();
            panel.width = 300;
            panel.height = 200;
            panel.title = "Hello";

            this.addElement(panel);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```

//MyPanel.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Panel xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
     width="150" height="80" title="Hello" 
     mouseDown="onMouseDown(event)" mouseUp="onMouseUp(event)" 
     skinClass="com.dragpanel.PanelNoTitleBar">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            this.startDrag();
        }

        protected function onMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            this.stopDrag();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:HGroup verticalAlign="bottom" x="10" y="10">
    <s:Label text="Name:"/>
    <s:TextInput width="60"/>
</s:HGroup>
</s:Panel>
```

Comment: Thanks for code but it is drag n drop, I want just moving my panel like in this example: http://blog.ninjacaptain.com/2008/06/draggable-panel-with-close-button/ but my panel without title bar

Comment: I have changed my code. Now it is only draggable. Not droppable :)

Answer (score 0):

How are you starting the drag using the title bar?  Do you have a mouseDown listener on the titlebar section of the Panel?  You can just move the mouseDown listener to the Panel itself.

Comment: Please can you explain me how to move mouseDown listener to the Panel itself?

Comment: Looks like you already got your answer.  Just so it's clear, in Anton's example: `<s:Panel ... mouseDown="onMouseDown(event)">`